# Eliminate "Go to app" step during authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the server side flow to authenticate users and ask them to authorize my app.  Everything works well but sometimes when I redirect to Facebook, the user first see's a page that makes them click a "Go to app" button to get to the authorization page where they authorize my app and the privileges requested.  I want to redirect right to the authorization page and skip this "Go to app" page.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
var facebookClient = new FacebookClient();
String RedirectUri = "page on my server";
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    { "redirect_uri", RedirectUri },
    { "client_id", "my client id" },
    { "scope", "publish_stream,manage_pages,email"}
};
String LoginUrl = facebookClient.GetLoginUrl(parameters).ToString();

Response.Redirect(LoginUrl, true);
```

Thanks this is driving me nuts ;)

Here is an example redirect url:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=MY-URI&client_id=My-CLIENT_ID&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages,email
```